# Laravel has and orHas not working with where

Tags: php, laravel

I need get categories with products, only where products exists on category, I have code:

```
 $categories = Category::with(['children.products', 'products'])->has('children.products')->orHas('products')->whereNull('parent_id')->whereId($category->id)->paginate(15);
```

But `whereId` = `$category->id` not working.. Why? I get category with other categories.. but I need get only certain category, where id = categoryId

Model category:

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'parent_id')->withoutGlobalScope('active');
}

public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the category id being looked up fulfills any of these conditions: _has a parent_, doesn't have products, doesn't have sub-categories with products

Answer (score 1):

You should combine has and orHas within enclosed function, something similar to below:

```
$query->where(function($query) {
  $query->has('children.products');
  $query->orHas('products');
});
```

Additionally, to above, I would recommend using "join" because "has" is a lot slower.